# socket to '/var/run/libvirt/virtxend-sock': File o directory not found

Tags: 20.04, virtualization, xen

I'm running xen on ubuntu 20.04 and I'm trying to create a new xen connection with virt-manager,but it does not work,because the error : "failed to connect socket to '/var/run/libvirt/-virtxend-sock. file or directory not found". I tried to do :

```
root@ziomario-I9:/etc/xen# systemctl status libvirtd
● libvirtd.service - Virtualization daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/libvirtd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2020-07-14 07:41:04 CEST; 14h ago
TriggeredBy: ● libvirtd-admin.socket
             ● libvirtd.socket
             ● libvirtd-ro.socket
       Docs: man:libvirtd(8)
             https://libvirt.org
   Main PID: 2376 (libvirtd)
      Tasks: 17 (limit: 32768)
     Memory: 41.0M
     CGroup: /system.slice/libvirtd.service
             └─2376 /usr/sbin/libvirtd

lug 14 21:31:19 ziomario-I9 libvirtd[2376]: End of file while reading data: Error di input/output
lug 14 21:33:15 ziomario-I9 libvirtd[2376]: Failed to connect socket to '/var/run/libvirt/virtxend-sock': File o directory not found
lug 14 21:33:15 ziomario-I9 libvirtd[2376]: End of file while reading data: Errore di input/output
lug 14 21:39:29 ziomario-I9 libvirtd[2376]: Failed to connect socket to '/var/run/libvirt/virtxend-sock': File o directory no>
lug 14 21:39:29 ziomario-I9 libvirtd[2376]: End of file while reading data: Error input/output
lug 14 21:41:13 ziomario-I9 libvirtd[2376]: operation failed: pool 'default' already exists with uuid 4794da80-c4ef-43a5-aee5>
lug 14 21:41:23 ziomario-I9 libvirtd[2376]: Failed to connect socket to '/var/run/libvirt/virtbhyved-sock': File or directory not found
lug 14 21:41:23 ziomario-I9 libvirtd[2376]: End of file while reading data: Errore di input/output
lug 14 21:41:46 ziomario-I9 libvirtd[2376]: Failed to connect socket to '/var/run/libvirt/virtxend-sock': File o directory no>
lug 14 21:41:46 ziomario-I9 libvirtd[2376]: End of file while reading data: Errore di input/output
```

I tried also to do :

```
sudo systemctl enable libvirtd
sudo systemctl start libvirtd
```

but I got the same result. what can I do ?

UPDATE :

```
root@ziomario-I9:/etc/xen# apt install libvirt-daemon-driver-xen

root@ziomario-I9:/etc/xen# sudo systemctl restart libvirtd

root@ziomario-I9:/etc/xen# systemctl status libvirtd
lines 1--1...skipping...
● libvirtd.service - Virtualization daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/libvirtd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead) since Wed 2020-07-15 18:14:28 CEST; 18s ago
TriggeredBy: ● libvirtd-admin.socket
             ● libvirtd.socket
             ● libvirtd-ro.socket
       Docs: man:libvirtd(8)
             https://libvirt.org
    Process: 31289 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/libvirtd $libvirtd_opts (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 31289 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

lug 15 18:14:27 ziomario-I9 systemd[1]: Starting Virtualization daemon...
lug 15 18:14:27 ziomario-I9 systemd[1]: Started Virtualization daemon.
lug 15 18:14:28 ziomario-I9 libvirtd[31289]: libvirt version: 6.0.0, package: 0ubuntu8.1 (Christian Ehrhardt <christian.ehrha>
lug 15 18:14:28 ziomario-I9 libvirtd[31289]: hostname: ziomario-I9
lug 15 18:14:28 ziomario-I9 libvirtd[31289]: Unable to configure libxl's memory management parameters
lug 15 18:14:28 ziomario-I9 libvirtd[31289]: Initialization of LIBXL state driver failed: no error
lug 15 18:14:28 ziomario-I9 libvirtd[31289]: Driver state initialization failed
lug 15 18:14:28 ziomario-I9 systemd[1]: libvirtd.service: Succeeded.
```

now the error is :

**libxenlight state driver is not active.**

LOG gathered this armor denials,but they appeared before to create the xen domain :

```
root@ziomario-I9:/home/ziomario# dmesg -w | grep apparmor
[    5.887830] evm: security.apparmor
[   31.653223] audit: type=1400 audit(1594897201.258:2): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="libreoffice-senddoc" pid=665 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   31.702186] audit: type=1400 audit(1594897201.306:3): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="libreoffice-xpdfimport" pid=672 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   31.802911] audit: type=1400 audit(1594897201.406:4): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="libreoffice-oopslash" pid=671 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   31.823300] audit: type=1400 audit(1594897201.430:5): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/ipsec/stroke" pid=663 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   31.953066] audit: type=1400 audit(1594897201.558:6): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="nvidia_modprobe" pid=669 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   31.953076] audit: type=1400 audit(1594897201.558:7): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="nvidia_modprobe//kmod" pid=669 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   31.966592] audit: type=1400 audit(1594897201.570:8): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/bin/man" pid=660 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   31.966601] audit: type=1400 audit(1594897201.570:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="man_filter" pid=660 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   31.966607] audit: type=1400 audit(1594897201.570:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="man_groff" pid=660 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   31.975582] audit: type=1400 audit(1594897201.582:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="lsb_release" pid=664 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   48.715193] audit: type=1400 audit(1594897218.322:59): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/{,usr/}sbin/dhclient" name="/proc/1733/task/1734/comm" pid=1733 comm="dhclient" requested_mask="wr" denied_mask="wr" fsuid=0 ouid=0
[   48.715835] audit: type=1400 audit(1594897218.322:60): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/{,usr/}sbin/dhclient" name="/proc/1733/task/1735/comm" pid=1733 comm="dhclient" requested_mask="wr" denied_mask="wr" fsuid=0 ouid=0
[   48.716222] audit: type=1400 audit(1594897218.322:61): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/{,usr/}sbin/dhclient" name="/proc/1733/task/1736/comm" pid=1733 comm="dhclient" requested_mask="wr" denied_mask="wr" fsuid=0 ouid=0
[  137.782108] audit: type=1400 audit(1594897307.641:62): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" profile="/usr/sbin/cups-browsed" pid=2396 comm="cups-browsed" capability=23  capname="sys_nice"
[  183.363064] audit: type=1400 audit(1594897353.229:63): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="docker-default" pid=3461 comm="apparmor_parser"
```

Comment: Hi @mark2020 checking a few common issues - do you have a related apparmor denial in `dmesg`? Furthermore that socket should only be needed if using split [daemons for virtxend](https://libvirt.org/daemons.html#modular-driver-daemons) which Ubuntu doesn't use in 20.04. But maybe you miss the function - libvirt xen support is now a separate not default installed package - consider installing libvirt-daemon-driver-xen and then restarting libvirtd.

Comment: refresh the page please. I added more informations. what should I do for adding the apparmor denial in dmesg ?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1259374/libxenlight-state-driver-is-not-active

Comment: Hi @mark2020, since this seems to be the answer to this issue I converted it to an answer that you can +1. I have suggested ideas on the follow on issue already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking a few common issues:

#1 do you have a related apparmor denial in dmesg?
You'd in one console run `dmesg -w` and then on another start your guest.
If the log gathered has any `appamor ... DENIED ...` messages check them and consider adding rules accordingly.

#2  Furthermore that socket should only be needed if using split daemons for virtxend which Ubuntu doesn't use in 20.04. But maybe you miss the function - libvirt xen support is now a separate not default installed package - consider installing `libvirt-daemon-driver-xen` and then restarting libvirtd.

```
apt install libvirt-daemon-driver-xen
systemctl restart libvirtd
```

Comment: refresh the page. It does not seems that the guest produced armor denials,but anyway,it still does not work.

Comment: I'm stil getting this error: failed to connect to the hypervisor error: internal error: libxenlight state driver is not active.