# libxenlight state driver is not active

Tags: server, 20.04, virtualization, xen

I'm trying to create a new xen connection with virt-manager. At the beginning it didn't work because this error : "**failed to connect socket to '/var/run/libvirt/-virtxend-sock. file or directory not found**" ; but then I followed the @Christian Ehrhardt suggestion on this thread :

[socket to '/var/run/libvirt/virtxend-sock': File o directory not found](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1259086/socket-to-var-run-libvirt-virtxend-sock-file-o-directory-not-found)

and the first error is gone,but now there is another error : "**libxenlight state driver is not active**". How to fix that ?

```
● libvirtd.service - Virtualization daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/libvirtd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2020-07-15 18:26:11 CEST; 23min ago
TriggeredBy: ● libvirtd-ro.socket
             ● libvirtd-admin.socket
             ● libvirtd.socket
       Docs: man:libvirtd(8)
             https://libvirt.org
   Main PID: 2376 (libvirtd)
      Tasks: 17 (limit: 32768)
     Memory: 77.4M
     CGroup: /system.slice/libvirtd.service
             └─2376 /usr/sbin/libvirtd

lug 15 18:26:09 ziomario-I9 libvirtd[2376]: Unable to open /dev/kvm: File o directory non esistente
lug 15 18:26:11 ziomario-I9 systemd[1]: Started Virtualization daemon.
lug 15 18:26:14 ziomario-I9 libvirtd[2376]: Unable to open /dev/kvm: File o directory non esistente
lug 15 18:32:36 ziomario-I9 libvirtd[2376]: Unable to open /dev/kvm: File o directory non esistente
lug 15 18:32:37 ziomario-I9 libvirtd[2376]: Unable to open /dev/kvm: File o directory non esistente
lug 15 18:32:37 ziomario-I9 libvirtd[2376]: internal error: Cannot find suitable CPU model for given data
lug 15 18:32:37 ziomario-I9 libvirtd[2376]: Unable to open /dev/kvm: File o directory non esistente
lug 15 18:32:37 ziomario-I9 libvirtd[2376]: operation failed: pool 'default' already exists with uuid 4794da80-c4ef-43a5-aee5>
lug 15 18:32:48 ziomario-I9 libvirtd[2376]: internal error: libxenlight state driver is not active
lug 15 18:32:48 ziomario-I9 libvirtd[2376]: End of file while reading data: Errore di input/output
```

~

```
root@ziomario-I9:/home/ziomario# virsh -c xen:///
error: failed to connect to the hypervisor
error: internal error: libxenlight state driver is not active

 root@ziomario-I9:/home/ziomario# virsh  version
Compiled against library: libvirt 6.0.0
Using library: libvirt 6.0.0
Using API: QEMU 6.0.0
Running hypervisor: QEMU 4.2.0
```

Comment: Normal qemu has no xen support anymore - not sure if that is it here thou - did you install `qemu-system-x86-xen` ?

Comment: thanks. I didn't do it. now I did it (installed qemu-system-x86-xen). what should I do now ?

Comment: but let me understand. with the installation of "qemu-system-x86-xen" , qemu-system-x86 is removed ? so,if I reboot and I switch to a non xen kernel,I should remove qemu-system-x86-xen and I should reinstall qemu-system-x86 ?

Comment: I'm stil getting this error: failed to connect to the hypervisor
error: internal error: libxenlight state driver is not active

Comment: @ChristianEhrhardt

Comment: I was off a while sorry, have you booted the xen kernel at all? If it looks like this you didn't `$ sudo xl list
ERROR:  Can't find hypervisor information in sysfs!`

Comment: yes man. yesterday I've been able to boot succesfully a phisical installation of windows 10 in dom U with the passed through graphic card (rtx 2080 ti),so the xen kernel is working right. but the "libxenlight state driver" is not active is still there. what should I do ?

Comment: root@ziomario-I9:/etc/xen# sudo xl list
Name                                        ID   Mem VCPUs State Time(s)
Domain-0                                     0 32066    16     r-----    1922.6

Comment: I have opened thig bug report,but no one replied yet ! https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/691920